# List as value of a dictionary gets None after calling __missing__

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nonetype

```
class ChapterDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        res = self[key] = []
        return res
```

I have this custom Dictionary. If a key does not exist yet, a new key:value pair should be created, whereas the value should be an empty list (of strings). Later on I have my instance

```
chapters = ChapterDict()
```

and would like to store values like that.

```
chapters[processed_key] = chapters[processed_key].append(section)
```

If I do

```
print(chapters)
```

I get `{'0': None, '1': None, '2': None, '3': None}` as a result, so the keys are right but the list is `None`.

What's my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` adds an element to a list and returns `None`, which you then assign (overwrite) the value for the given key. Drop the assignment and you should be fine:

```py
chapters[processed_key].append(section)
```